# Tying session across website, chrome extension and google web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, chrome-web-store

I have GA code installed on a  website, chrome extension and chrome web store (when user goes to download the extension). Currently there are 3 sessions firing and I want to get this down to a single session.
I have implemented cross domain tracking for such scenarios but this won't hold true as extension works differently and web store implementation has limitations.

Anybody here faced same issue?

Thanks!